# RMagick can not read remote image

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

My env is Linux centos, and use ruby 1.8.7, and the code is here below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
Magick::Image.read("http://image.domain.com/image.darenhui.com/images/random_bg/01.jpg")[0]
```

it throws error like below:

```
in `read': no decode delegate for this image format `//image.domain.com/images/random_bg/01.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532 (Magick::ImageMagickError),
```

but if i read from local like:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'RMagick'
    Magick::Image.read("/local/staticimages/random_bg/01.jpg")[0]
```

everything is ok. 
I run identify -list format and see below:

```
     JPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (62)
     JPG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (62)
```

but when i test by identity for "http://image.domain.com/image.darenhui.com/images/random_bg/01.jpg" to fail, but success for "/local/staticimages/random_bg/01.jpg"

Can someone give me some clue? thank you in advance.

Comment: what happens if you copy&paste that URL and feed it to wget ?

Comment: @Yahia thank you for your reply, i tried wget http://image.domain.com/images/random_bg/06.jpg, it's ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see `Magick::Image.read` does NOT support URLs, only files/file handles - see http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#read where it says that it

> Reads all the images from the specified file.

It is implemented by the C function `ReadImage` which does not support URLs - see the ImageMagick source at line 394 [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/constitute_8c_source.html).

IF you want to open an image from a URL you need to download the image somehow - to a file or a stream... then you can feed that file or stream to `Magick...`

Comment: The link above is broken. This question needs an updated accepted answer.

Answer (score 46):

`Magick::Image.read` does not support URL links. But you can read the remote image using ruby `open` method:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'RMagick'
 require "open-uri"


image = Magick::ImageList.new  
urlimage = open("http://www.jewelinfo4u.com/images/Gallery/ruby.jpg") # Image Remote URL 
image.from_blob(urlimage.read)

# crop = image.crop(10,10,200,300) You can crop this image too
# crop.write('C:/nameofyourNewImage.jpg') If you want to save the image you can use this line in windows
```

Answer (score 7):

Fast forward to May 2014, and I'm able to just...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
include Magick
image = ImageList.new("http://www.jewelinfo4u.com/images/Gallery/ruby.jpg")
```

And it just works. Feels good.

(Tested on ImageMagick 6.8.8-9 Q16)

EDIT: Does not seem work on Heroku Cedar stack (ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2012-08-17 Q16) though. :/

Comment: If you need to use Image, then do the above and simply do a       image=image_list.cur_image and you're good to go

Comment: Also does not work if your URL is HTTPS, as I just found out.

Comment: it does for me, @TGPrankster. It's possible that they fixed the issue since you posted

Answer (score 2):

You can read a file from a url with `open-uri`, then feed that into Rmagick's `Image::from_blob`.

Example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'rubygems'
require 'Rmagick'

image_url = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'

image = Magick::Image.from_blob(open(image_url).read).first
```

Note that you should additionally take care to handle exceptions arising from the `open` HTTP request. Ie, what happens if you get a 404, or a non-image response?

Answer (score 0):

As of `rmagick (4.1.2)`, `Image.read` does support URL links. In my case, I was reading an image, specifically a `png` file from AWS S3. This was via localhost. Updating to the latest version should fix this problem.