# RMagick image type detection failing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, imagemagick, rmagick

We're using RMagick to identify image types in cases where the file extensions are unavailable or wrong. The `format` attribute works on my local Mac dev box, but on Heroku it returns nil...

```
irb> require 'RMagick'
irb> image = Magick::Image::read('https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.appgrinders.test/images/dog.gif')[0]
irb> image.format
=> nil
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the same version of ImageMagick/RMagick on both machines?

Comment: @dlemstra - Same version of RMagick (2.13.2) though just noticed that ImageMagick on my Mac is version 6.8.0-10 while Heroku is running version 6.5.7-8, though there's nothing in the ImageMagick change log that would indicate that matters

Comment: The `identify` check that @Adriano suggested is the best way to find out, but still, can you try using [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) and see what that outputs? They both use the same ImageMagick but still just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is due to ImageMagick not being able to read remote images (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7264895/165673)) though strangely the problem only manifests itself on Heroku(?). The underlying ImageMagick format returns 'HTTPS', while RMagick format returns nil.

On my Mac:

```
$ identify -verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.appgrinders.test/images/dog.gif

Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
...
```

On Heroku:

```
$ identify -verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.appgrinders.test/images/dog.gif

Format: HTTPS
...
```

So then the answer is to copy the image locally and read it there.

Comment: Heroku doesn't have a local file system.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look on ImageMagick page, you can see the command responsible for these informations about the image file.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

Do you tried run the command identify in Heroku console?

Look:

```
$  identify image.jpg
=> image.jpg JPEG 960x960 960x960+0+0 8-bit sRGB 89KB 0.010u 0:00.009
```

or:

```
$ identify -verbose image.jpg 

Image: image.jpg
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 960x960+0+0
Units: Undefined
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
```

Can you upgrade the ImageMagick on the Heroku?

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and while the format returns correctly on both platforms for local images, it fails on Heroku for remote images- see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was as easy as removing the https in the s3 url for the image I was trying to convert.

```
image_url = image_url.gsub('https://', 'http')
```

Now I can convert any image. My bucket can serve content from http and https.